# Как установить aiogram для python 3.9 в ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, aiogram, python-3.9

Помогите, пожалуйста, у меня **`Ubuntu 20.04`**, я установил **`python 3.9`**. 
Теперь хочу установить для него `aiogram`, но когда пишу `python3.9 -m pip install aiogram`, 
консоль выдает такую ошибку:

> from distutils.cmd import Comman as DistUtilsCommand 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'".

Что в таком случае надо делать?

Comment: Ну, установить этот самый distutils, наверное? `apt install python3.9-distutils`

Answer (score -1):

```
apt install python3.9-distutils
```

Comment: Это не ответ, а просто скопированный комментарий `@andreymal`. Даже не скопированный комментарий, а скопированная половина комментария.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]